# Which way to use a crown race removal tool?

Tags: fork, headset, tools, steerer, crownrace

I purchased the following crown race removal tool: http://www.birzman.com/products_2.php?uID=2&cID=24&Key=106

It has a flat side and a side with 45 degree chamfered edge. I suppose the idea is that tightening the tool, the chamfer pushes the crown race away from the steerer tube bottom.

There are also holes for threaded rod that I suppose could be used as an additional force to remove the crown race by pulling the tool away from the fork crown.

My question is: in which way should the tool be used? (The tool was not supplied with instructions). Should the flat side point upwards towards the crown race and the 45 degree chamfer point downwards towards the fork crown? Or the other way around?

My intuition is that the flat side should be placed towards the crown race and the chamfer towards the fork crown, but I'd like to be certain.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a picture of instructions for a tool similar to yours.

[image]

This picture shows putting a screwdriver in the holes to drive out the crown race.
Since yours are threaded I'd put a bolt in each hole and hammer on that. Not a fan of hammering screwdrivers.

Here's another similar tool close up to indicate orientation.
[image]

Comment: Thanks, seems to be the exact opposite of what I imagined! I would have used it exactly the wrong way around. I bought some threaded rod, so when using the tool I'd much rather put a piece of wood on top of where the steerer tube ends, drill a couple of holes for the threaded rod in the wood, and use the threaded rod to gradually pull away the crown race. I'm not a fan of hammers, if something can be accomplished with a screw thread and a hammer I'll use the screw thread.

Comment: Instead of the inadequate screw-driver I'd rather use a punch as a better suited tool.

Answer (score 1):

Here are posted instructions from a review of a similar tool:

> The key to using this is not to overdo it. Just tighten the tool
> slowly and evenly enough to get the edges under the crown race then
> turn the fork around and tap the tool as shown in the video. Tighten
> the tool a little more and again turn upside down and tap a little
> more. Little by little and the crown race just pops off when upside
> down tapping. Do not try to tighten the tool all the way to pop the
> crown race in one shot. Oh and lubricate the crown race and tool with
> grease prior to using.

Another commenter reports marginal results:

> One year and four attempts at using this tool: time for an update. I
> recently pulled an FSA steel crown race - that had been installed only
> 4 months – from an aluminum steerer. The bike was used solely on an
> indoor trainer, so the installation was super clean and I wanted to
> sell the almost-new fork. I liberally used Teflon lubricant and worked
> extremely slowly. This tool still produced small gouges in the
> aluminum crown. I don't know if this is due to the Ice Toolz design or
> due to the nature of this style of race remover. I've included images
> of the scratches left in an almost new suspension fork.
>
> This is a home-shop or infrequent use tool that produces marginal
> results. I will continue to use this tool for low end repairs. But for
> high end forks (particularly carbon), I will pay to have a local shop
> remove the fork race using a Park CRP-2.

[image]

Comment: I suspect the scratching could be avoided by putting a threaded rod through the two holes and using the threaded rod to pull the crown race away. My understanding is that the scratching happens due to hammering on the tool instead of gently pulling it upwards using the threaded rods.

Comment: @juhist There are a lot of forks and races in the world now that when combined offer zero overhang of the crown race. Situations like this are the reason why tools like this one have become mainstream, compared to the many decades where a traditional U-shaped one was all that was needed. It's hard to absolutely avoid some marking/scarring of the fork crown with any of the types that start by wedging themselves in, just by nature of how what they're doing is ramming a hardened steel blade against an aluminum fork.